# Animate.scss not fully compiling [screenshot]

Tags: animation, sass

I'm trying to compile Animate.scss (by [Geoff Graham](http://geoffgraham.me/animate-scss/)) but all that's appearing in "style.css" is a tiny portion of the CSS. 
I'm using Ruby "sass --watch scss/dir.scss:style.css" to compile and it works correctly for other partials (e.g. Bootstrap 4, whch is commented out in the first column in "dir.scss") but I can't figure out why the Animate library is having this issue. Ruby command terminal is not showing any errors.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Used the latest release on github (3.2.2) and now it's working.